# Error while extracting response for type [class java.lang.Object] and content type [application/octet-stream];

Tags: java, resttemplate

Here is the method that I have ,

**what does the API that I call actually returns?** 
This will return binary response and the response content is "application/octet-stream".
 The method which calls this method is from controller which will return ResponseEntity<byte[]> to the front end.

```
 @Override
public <V> ResponseEntity<V> getBillingDocPDFFromGCP(String url, HttpMethod method, HttpServletRequest request, String accessToken, Class<V> responseType, Map<String, String> params, BaseStoreModel baseStore, String appDomain) {
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(url)) {
        throw new ConfigurationException(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE + " : Missing API Uri property in configuration");
    }
    LOG.info("getGCPBillingDocPDF API URL...{}", url);
    MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = getServiceHeadersForGCPPDF(baseStore, accessToken);
    final HttpEntity<Object> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
    final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.ALL));
    messageConverters.add(converter);
    restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);

    try {
        return (ResponseEntity<V>) restTemplate.exchange(url, method, requestEntity, responseType);


    } catch (final HttpClientErrorException httpClientException) {
        LOG.error(UNAUTHORIZED_ERROR + " : " + httpClientException.getMessage(), httpClientException);
        throw new HttpClientErrorException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, httpClientException.getMessage());
    } catch (final RestClientException restClientException) {
        LOG.error(REST_CLIENT_ERROR, restClientException);
        throw new RestClientException(REST_CLIENT_REPORTED_ERROR + " : " + restClientException.getMessage(), restClientException);
    }
}

  public MultiValueMap<String, String> getServiceHeadersForGCPPDF(final BaseStoreModel baseStore, final String aceToken) {
    final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    final String siteId = getCurrentSiteId(baseStore);
    headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/octet-stream"));
    headers.add("X-API-Key", value);
    return headers;
}
```

and below is the error am getting ,please advise how to resolve this issue

```
 Rest Client Error org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while xtracting response for type [class java.lang.Object] and content type [application/octet-stream]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Unexpected character ('%' (code 37)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false'); nested exception is
```

Please advise

**Updated Method with return type configured as ResponseEntity<byte[]>:**

As per Michael suggestions I changed the return type as ResponseEntity<byte[]> but am stilling getting same error

```
 @Override
public <V> ResponseEntity<byte[]> getBillingDocPDFFromGCP(String url, HttpMethod method, HttpServletRequest request, String accessToken, Class<V> responseType, Map<String, String> params, BaseStoreModel baseStore, String appDomain) {
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(url)) {
        throw new ConfigurationException(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE + " : Missing API Uri property in configuration");
    }
    LOG.info("getGCPBillingDocPDF API URL...{}", url);
    MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = getServiceHeadersForGCPPDF(baseStore, accessToken);
    final HttpEntity<Object> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
    final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.ALL));
    messageConverters.add(converter);
    restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);

    try {
        return  restTemplate.exchange(url, method, requestEntity, byte[].class);

    } catch (final HttpClientErrorException httpClientException) {
        LOG.error(UNAUTHORIZED_ERROR + " : " + httpClientException.getMessage(), httpClientException);
        throw new HttpClientErrorException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, httpClientException.getMessage());
    } catch (final RestClientException restClientException) {
        LOG.error(REST_CLIENT_ERROR, restClientException);
        throw new RestClientException(REST_CLIENT_REPORTED_ERROR + " : " + restClientException.getMessage(), restClientException);
    }
}
```

Error that I am still getting is

```
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while extracting response for type [class [B] and content type [application/octet-stream]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Unexpected character ('%' (code 37)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('%' (code 37)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error and expected return type `[application/octet-stream]` you expect to receive binary information. But your method returns `ResponseEntity<V>` By the way you don't show how you call your method and what is your type V actually is. The converter that receives your response expects a valid JSON and in the error, it complains that the returned content is NOT a valid JSON. So, what does the API that you call actually returns? is it a binary info as the header value `[application/octet-stream]` suggests or is it textual JSON info? If it is JSON then you have a wrong response type. If it is a binary info then your type V should be a byte array or `ByteBuffer`.

I also may suggest you to use a much simpler HTTP client than a RestTemplate. Especially if your return type is really a binary information. In this case the Http client that I suggest actually has methods that return `ByteBuffer`you can deal with it on your own and not worry about telling your Http client to what it should be converted and how. This Http client comes with MgntUtils Open Source java library that is written and maintained by me. Also this Http client allows for multiple requests without resetting URL and headers for each request if you are sending requests to the same URL.
Here is how your code may look like:

```
public class MyHttpClient {
  private HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

  public MyHttpClient() {
     client.setConnectionUrl(myUrlStr);
     client.setRequestHeader(headerName1Str, headerValue1Str)
     .setRequestHeader(headerName2Str, headerValue2Str)
     .setRequestHeader(headerName3Str, headerValue3Str);     
  }

  public ByteArray getBillingDocPDFFromGCP(...) {
    ByteBuffer result = null;
    try {
      //Here you can change connection URL if it is different than the pre-set one 
      // and add or modify headers
      HttpClient.HttpMethod httpMethod = HttpClient.HttpMethod.valueOf(httpMethodStr);
      ResponseHolder<ByteBuffer> response = sendHttpRequestForBinaryResponse(httpMethod);
      result = response.getResponseContent();
   } catch(HttpClientCommunicationException e) {
      ResponseHolder errorResponse  = e.getResponseHolder();
      logger.error(errorResponse.getResponseCode() + " " + errorResponse.getResponseMessage());
  }
  return result;
}
```

Here is [JavaDoc for the HttpClient class](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/lifecycle/management/httpclient/HttpClient.html).
The MgntUtils library can be obtained as [maven artifact](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) or from [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) (including source code and Javadoc)

Comment: Hi @Michael , thanks a lot for your inputs really appreciate that  ,am sorry I may not able to use the above methad as the method that I have given is a common one which is used in few other use cases.I have updated the code once again and getting similar error.Could you please review and advise what am doing wrong please.